# What are the drop rates for the different rarities in Loot Boxes?

Tags: overwatch

Loot Boxes can have items with rarities from Common, Rare, Epic, and Legendary.

What I'd like to know is, with the nature of Loot Boxes, what are the drop rates of Common/Rare/Epic/Legendary items? I'd especially like to know what are the chances to get a Legendary skin from a Loot Box.

For example, in TF2, Valve has made all crates a 1% flat chance to get an Unusual Hat.   In CS:GO, it's the same thing, with a 1% to get an Exceedingly Rare Special Item.  In Overwatch, what are my chances of getting a specific rarity from a Loot Box?

Comment: fyi: both tf2 and csgo unusual and knife drop rates are below 1%.

Comment: Personal experience makes it seem similar to a Hearthstone style thing where you're guaranteed at least one item of blue quality.

Comment: according to this site, there is a "pity limit" of at least 1 legendary after 25 boxes.  http://www.pcgamesn.com/overwatch/overwatch-loot-legendary-skin-chance

Comment: Blizzard released some numbers, answer bellow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no published drop rates as such but [here is a link to a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4mbpz9/loot_box_drop_rate_1000_boxes_sample_size/) which has compiled a list of percentages over 1000 crates by various people compiled into one list. It's still a small sample size in the grand scheme of things but it's better than individual stats. To follow the links below you can use the Reddit thread.

```
Video link          Common  Rare    Epic    Legendary
Force               235     125     31      9
Royal               113     66      15      6
Futile              116     67      15      6
Jeel                118     64      14      4
Boogie2988          117     64      18      5
DrFeelgood          121     60      13      6
Masier              117     64      14      5
MFPallytime         237     132     27      8
Stylosa             245     125     28      6
Drift0r             116     58      15      7
Redmercy            234     125     33      12
Nero                238     121     29      8
Outfoxed            284     167     31      14
Gamespot            121     65      14      4
Total count         2412    1303    297     100
Percent of Total    58.66%  31.69%  7.22%   2.43%
Drop rate           97.08%  78.22%  25.91%  9.38%
```

Comment: That's useful. Copy over the table and you'll get a much better response. I'm holding my upvote until that happens. That being said, it sounds like he just looked at videos on youtube, which isn't exactly a random sample.

Comment: I can't import the whole table as I'm unsure of how to put links inside a <pre> tag.

Comment: That works. As long as the information is here. +1

Answer (score 7):

Blizzard (China) just revealed some numbers, at least for now it is not know if these numbers apply for China only, or for China and any other region.

- Every Loot Box contains one item of **Rare** (blue) or higher quality **100%** of the time.
- For every 5.5 boxes opened (**18.2%**), a **Epic** item (purple) will be inside.
- For every 13.5 boxes opened (**7.4%**), a **Legendary** (gold) item will be inside.

It is believed that these numbers are valid worldwide but this is not yet confirmed. They are confirmed to apply for China. I'll update as soon as more information is available.

Blizzard did not actually release percentages, but they were calculated by a few places, including [PC Gamer](http://www.pcgamer.com/blizzard-reveals-overwatch-loot-box-drop-rates-in-china/).

Comment: No problem! I was just asking on that other question about adding this information and saw you were a step ahead :)

Answer (score -2):

odds are for getting any of the following:
Rare - 15 in 10 loot crates
Epic - 3 in 10 loot crates
Legendary - 1 in 15 loot crates
I'm not sure what the odds for getting a specific item are, but I hope this was helpful. :-)

Comment: Sounds believable, but I'm curious where you got this information, since these figures are pretty exact.

Comment: You have a source for that?

Comment: "15 in 10"? That's an awful lot of rares.

Comment: That would be because of a guaranteed rare, much like Hearthstone, combined with the chance for one or more of the other items to also roll as rare.

Comment: @JeremyAvalon You think he means you get 15 rares in 10 crates? That makes more sense. I'm reading that as opening 10 crates results in 15 that have rares, which is nonsense.

Comment: That's my reading, but probably because the double-rare is fresh in my head since I just got such a box. I agree the wording is poor and ambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

I personally opened 40 boxes and got 1 legendary.

I don't think we can truly tell the % rate for now, unless Blizzard releases a statement, or we can get a large sample of openings and make some % ourselves with those results.